# Increasing the DRYness with a Simple Wrapping Class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, dry

There has to be a better way to do this:

```
require 'log4r'

class PaddedLogger

  attr_accessor :logger, :padding

  def initialize(args)
    @logger = Log4r::Logger.new args[:name]
    @padding = args[:padding]
  end

  def debug(system, message)
    system = "[#{system}]"
    @logger.debug "#{system.ljust(@padding)}#{message}"
  end

  def info(system, message)
    system = "[#{system}]"
    @logger.info "#{system.ljust(@padding)}#{message}"
  end

  def warn(system, message)
    system = "[#{system}]"
    @logger.warn "#{system.ljust(@padding)}#{message}"
  end

  def error(system, message)
    system = "[#{system}]"
    @logger.error "#{system.ljust(@padding + 3)}#{message}"
  end

  def fatal(system, message)
    system = "[#{system}]"
    @logger.fatal "#{system.ljust(@padding + 3)}#{message}"
  end
end
```

It's just a wrapping class to help me get my log4r logs appearing in a specific format, and it works exactly as I need it too, but surely Ruby's meta-programming magic can simplify this so I don't have to constantly repeat myself.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to provide a custom formatter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
require 'log4r'

class PaddedLogger

  attr_accessor :logger, :padding

  def initialize(args)
    @logger = Log4r::Logger.new args[:name]
    @padding = args[:padding]
  end

  [:debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal].each do |reason|
    define_method reason do |system, message|
      system = "[#{system}]"
      @logger.send reason, "#{system.ljust(@padding)}#{message}"
    end
  end

end
```

And while you're at it, why not collapse the two lines in the `define_method` block to one?

```
@logger.send reason, "[#{system}]".ljust(@padding) + message
```

Comment: I added:
'''padding = @padding
'''padding += 3 if reason == :error || reason == :fatal
'''@logger.send reason, "[#{system}]".ljust(padding) + message
Can I condense that too?

Comment: You can by use of the ternary `... ? ... : ...`, but that would bloat the size of the line. Unless there's a relation between the length (nbr of chars) of the `reason` you're better off doing this on a separate line.

Comment: `added_padding = [:error, :fatal].include?(reason) ? 0 : 3`

Answer (score 0):

Here is and alternative solution using method_missing:

```
class TestClass

  @@methods = [:upcase, :other_methods_to_catch]

  def initialize
    @message = 'hello'
  end 

  def method_missing name, *args
     super unless @@methods.include? name
     @message.send(name, *args)
  end

end 

x = TestClass.new

p x.upcase #=> HELLO
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be a bit slower?

Comment: Maybe a little, but ruby frequently make this kind of checking of methods at different level, so it is pretty good at doing that without too much of a loss. The cool thing about method missing is that it is possible to dynamically add and remove things during runtime. But as you do not seems to really need that, svoops answer is probable safer and the correct way to go in this case.